# Rails 4/Heroku '404 not found' page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been following Michael Hartl's ruby on rails screencasts, however I have the older Rails 3 ones and not the videos for Rails 4. So far it hasn't been much of an issue, but I would like to have my app deploying to heroku and following his instructions leads me to a 404 not found page for the home screen.

When navigating around (i.e. manually entering in pages/home) it brings me to the static HTML pages, but doesn't load any CSS etc.

I looked through Heroku's site and they mentioned to install rails_serve_static_assets. I did

```
gem install rails_serve_static_assets
bundle install
```

as well as added rails_serve_static_assets to my Gemfile like this:

```
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'
end
```

Everything pushes just fine, it says it's deployed, but when I refresh the page it still gives me a 404 not found page.

What do I need to do to have it deploy correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see any error messages when you run: "heroku logs" ? Additionally, this the Heroku assets guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Isn't it `gem 'rails_12factor'` for heroku? Regarding the 404 on the home screen sound like your routes.rb leeds to nothing. And `index.html` in the public folder is deprecated since rails4

Comment: do you have routes for pages or is it in the public, can you post your `routes` file

Comment: So I guess I screwed something up with git because now it's rolled me back several versions. Let me figure this out and I'll post the routes file.

Comment: Do you have your database set up?